# When is it acceptable to work on coding a new page without a final comp?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web development. I have been writing css in the css file for a html element immediately after creating that element in html. That is giving me some problems. So my question is when should i start writing my css file. Should i wait till my entire html is complete if not then when is the exact stage i can start writing the css file?

Comment: What do you mean problems?

Comment: This question is waaaaaay too broad.

Comment: After adding css adjacent divs start overlapping with one another.Borders of div comes out of the main container class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working HTML / CSS in more than 2 years so I can say it is better to start with HTML mark up then after that fixed the layout using CSS.

Divide it into three parts.

1. Header section - create HTML then CSS
2. Content section - create HTML then CSS
3. Footer section - create HTML then CSS

On my style, I started with the header section then next is footer section and last is content.

Page section screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem i face is in the content section. giving css to the divs in the content section. borders of one div gets overlapped on another div !! I'll try your way  then first creating the html for the entire content section and then adding the css

Comment: Can you create an example of your HTML / CSS on http://fiddle.jshell.net/ ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ashish_shetty/jen59r3L/embedded/result/.

Comment: this was the page i was trying to make

Comment: Try to use float: left flor left content, float: right for right content instead of position absolute. Then put a separator on every section just like on this [**example**](https://jsfiddle.net/anthonypagaycarbon/dmbag1b4/). Use the [HTML5 reset css](http://anthonypagaycarbon.iblogger.org/wp-content/themes/anthony/css/html5reset.css), HTML5 standard coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you begin, you should write CSS and HTML in the same time, and often look if there are no problems.